# Delete rows that are in SUM function = 0 and with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have aggregation table (Players_Tournaments) of two others table: Players and Tournament. In aggregation table I save points for each player and each tournament. Tournaments have also relationship with table Season which defined in which Season was Tournament (etc. 2020, 2019...).
I want to delete rows from Player_Tournaments which are zeroes. But I want to delete only rows when they are grouped by Season in SUM gives zeroes. Becaues when I entering points for players in each tournament i get list of all my players and if they dont play they automaticly get 0 points. The main reason why I want to do this because many player didn't play all season and I want to delete those records.

I hope that was enough detailed.

**EDIT:**

Players_Tournaments: Player_id, Tournament_id, Points

Player: id, name...

Tournament: id, name, season_id...

Season: id, year

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I added which columns in tables are needed for this

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the rows from a result set, you would use a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(points) <> 0
```

Comment: But I also need to define that sums only for Tournaments in that Season